# How to delete original images from Save As HTML in Microsoft Word

Tags: image, vba, ms-word

I am saving the active document as an HTML file, which automatically produces a sub folder containing all of the the document's inline shapes (pictures). I used this code for that:

```
ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:=HTMLPath, _
 FileFormat:=wdFormatHTML, AddToRecentFiles:=True
```

This is exactly what I want, however for each image in the document it saves either one or two files. one if in Word, the image was untouched. But any manipulation (resize, coloring, crop, etc) will cause this HTML save to produce an original image version and edited. I want to delete the originals. the images are just incremented like image001.png, image002.png, etc so I can't compare file names and the file sizes might be different, etc.

How can I determine if in the Active Document that the image is original or edited? By having that information, I assume I can delete every other image (if all are edited) or track which ones are and which ones aren't.

If I have a loop like this, can store an array or something to figure out which ones are original or edited.

```
For Each oILShp In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
    'if oILShp is not edited, add current index to array
    'loop through array and delete images that have an original and edited version
Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thing this is not possible, because the original image is shown in Internet Explorer (with filters, like cropping), while the second one is shown in other browsers.

**Solution for non-IE browsers**

When you delete original file, it will be visible only in non-IE browsers. If you want go this way, open HTML file as string and search, where every file is listed. If is file name preceded by a tag "v:imagedata", delete it. For example

```
<v:imagedata src="x_files/image001.jpg"
```

If it is preceded by a tag "img", don´t delete it:

```
<img width=181 height=241 src="x_files/image002.jpg"
```

**Solution for Internet Explorer only** is change setting of Word:

- On the Tools menu, click Options.
- Click the General tab, and then click Web Options.
- Click the Browsers tab.
- Under Options, select the Rely on VML for displaying graphics in browsers check box.

or in VBA easily

```
ActiveDocument.WebOptions.RelyOnVML = True
```

...and save document. Big disadvantage is that images will be visible only in Internet Explorer.

**Solution for all browsers**

When you are saving document, use

```
 FileFormat:=WdSaveFormat.wdFormatFilteredHTML
```

Image file will be only one, but original is lost (for next editing in word), and some formating will be lost. Note, that in non-IE browsers will be the look of document the same as with full formating, minor differences will be visible only in IE and in Word.